# Axios always runs .then with invalid url

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I am using axios to make a HTTP get a call, if I specify an invalid URL axios runs the .then() as if it was successful. How to I get it to error if it can't find the url

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class AxiosRequest extends Component {
  render() {
    axios
      .get("invalidurl")

      .then(response => {
        console.log("Axios request successful...or was it, No it wasnt");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Axios request error", err);
      });

    return <h1>Axios Request</h1>;
  }
}
```

Running sandbox to show the issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/9lmn7316kp

Comment: check the network tab, its making the request to codesandbox server and that server is returning 200. To make a wrong call specify the full incorrect url like: `http://invalid`, now it will fail and execute the catch part. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0170py856l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is if you open the "Network" console in you web browser, you will see the request being made is to the webpage you are currently on (the sandbox), thus returning a 200. If you put in a real url such as http://google.com/ you will see the correct return.